# R Session on Linux - submit multiple batch jobs pointing to same session

Tags: r, linux, session

1) Is it possible to start R sessions on Linux (e.g. Rsession1) and submit multiple jobs in batch mode to the same R Session (e.g. job1 to Rsession1 and then later on based on user action submit job2 to Rsession1)?

This is equivalent to opening interactive R Session and submitting job1 and the user can submit job2 in same session (which will be available until the user closes interactive R session)

2) Is it possible to start two R sessions on Linux (e.g. Rsession1 and Rsession2) and submit multiple jobs in batch mode but specify session-id during job submission?

This is equivalent to opening two interactive R Sessions and submitting jobs to different R sessions by clicking on the window manually submitting the job.

Comment: Why? What are your trying to accomplish? Without more details this is difficult to answer; e.g. what do you mean with 'batch mode'? The 'normal' way of doing batch like processing is with `Rscript` but then each batch/script runs in its own R-session which is generally what one wants, but apparently this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: The short answer is "yes" to both questions. There are tons of ways to accomplish each task. You should provide some more detail (for instance what a user action button is and why running a couple of scripts through `Rscript` is not enough for the second question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but have you considered something like the `futures` package that will allow R to send work off to another thread to be completed?  That way the work can be done but doesn't lock up the main R session while the work is being completed. This way, via the main R session, you could launch job1 and then while that was still being worked on, launch job2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `save.image` at the end of each job to store the workspace and `load` at the beginning of the following jobs to restore it.
By choosing different file names the session-id could be specified.